# Enabling music while the iPhones goes hold during a call

Tags: iphone

I need to create an app which enables the caller in the other end to hear music while I press hold on my iPhone. This music will be selected from my library. Is there any API or anything which can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no public iOS API by with an app can either send or receive audio from the Phone app during a phone call.  The security sandbox will prevent even a private API from doing this on a stock OS device.